# npm package installation in hyper

Tags: node.js, npm, hyper

While installing any npm package in hyper, it's showing an error

For eg

npm install bus

gives an error

**UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE**

*Whats wrong here and how to resolve it?*